# Oracle order by via JPA with numeric first

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have column data like this in my db

```
data 
-----
1
2
A
3
4
B
```

I have below nls settings in place

```
SELECT * From NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS    .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_COMP    BINARY
```

When I query the db for `**select data from <mytable> order by data **` I am getting the result as below

```
data
-----
1
2
3
4
A
B
```

The same query via hibernate is giving the results with alphabets first and numeric later

```
data
-----
A
B
1
2
3
4
```

But, I want column to be displayed with numbers first and alphabets later via hibernate

```
data
------
1
2
3
4
A
B
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regularexpressions to sort in such a way,

```
select data from <mytable> order by REGEXP_REPLACE(data ,'[^0-9]'), REGEXP_REPLACE(data ,'[0-9]')
```

Comment: Thanks jim, But,  is there anyway I can have the data sorted by setting NLS Parameters. I am just looking for something by setting NLS parameters.

Comment: This is SQL standard and cannot be configured in NLS parameters

Comment: JIm, I just edited the question with more info now. Could you please check now

Answer (score 0):

That depends on `NLS_SORT` parameter's value. For example, in my database it is set to `CROATIAN` and the result is what you wanted:

```
SQL> select * From nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';

PARAMETER            VALUE
-------------------- --------------------
NLS_SORT             CROATIAN

SQL> with test (data) as
  2    (select '1' from dual union all
  3     select '2' from dual union all
  4     select 'A' from dual union all
  5     select '3' from dual union all
  6     select '4' from dual union all
  7     select 'B' from dual
  8    )
  9  select data
 10  from test
 11  order by data;

D
-
A
B
1
2
3
4

6 rows selected.
```

---

However, in your database, `NLS_SORT = BINARY`. Let's try it:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort = 'BINARY';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (data) as
  2    (select '1' from dual union all
  3     select '2' from dual union all
  4     select 'A' from dual union all
  5     select '3' from dual union all
  6     select '4' from dual union all
  7     select 'B' from dual
  8    )
  9  select data
 10  from test
 11  order by data;

D
-
1
2
3
4
A
B

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Right; the *wrong* result.

---

Therefore, modify `NLS_SORT`, if that's an option. See valid values by

```
SQL> select * From v$nls_valid_values where parameter = 'SORT';

PARAMETER            VALUE                ISDEP
-------------------- -------------------- -----
SORT                 BINARY               FALSE
SORT                 WEST_EUROPEAN        FALSE
SORT                 XWEST_EUROPEAN       FALSE
SORT                 GERMAN               FALSE
<snip>
```

Comment: I have SORT parameter set to BINARY andI am getting as expected in SQL Developer but, the same query via java hibernate is giving the results in reverse order - Alphabets first and then numeric numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the two options below should work,

1. Use NLSSORT function in the `order by` clause explicitly.

`select * from my_table order by NLSSORT(data,'NLS_SORT=BINARY');`

2. Create a function based index on the column,

`create index mytable_nlssort_index on my_table(nlssort(data, 'nls_sort=''BINARY'''))`

Use the query as below when the column is indexed.

`select data from my_table order by data;`